# How to push data to firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I know how to push data to firebase database, but I have a problem. Let me show my code first:

My java class looks like this:

```
public void btn_continue(View view) {
        final String str_c2c = c2c.getText().toString().trim();
        final String str_amount = samount.getText().toString().trim();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(str_c2c) && str_amount != null){
            lareview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lasend.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            amount.setText(str_amount);

            mDatabaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
            mDatabaseUsers.child(str_c2c).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String u_name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    target_name.setText(u_name);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    target_name.setText("Your target user was not found!");
                    target_name.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void btn_confirm(View view) {
        final String str_balance = balance.getText().toString().trim();
        Double d_balance = Double.parseDouble(str_balance);
        final String str_c2c = c2c.getText().toString().trim();
        final String str_amount = samount.getText().toString().trim();
        //change todouble
        final Double d_samount = Double.parseDouble(str_amount);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(str_c2c) && str_amount != null){
            if (d_samount>d_balance){
                Toast.makeText(Transfer.this, "Amount cant be higher than your balance", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                lareview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                lasend.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                mDatabaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                mDatabaseUsers.child(str_c2c).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        final String userID = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                        final long PostTime = new Date().getTime();
                        String str_posttime = Long.toString(PostTime);
                        String u_name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                        String u_tagetbalance = dataSnapshot.child("balance").getValue().toString();
                        Double d_tagetbalance = Double.parseDouble(u_tagetbalance);
                        Double d_bala = Double.parseDouble(str_balance);
                        Double send_amount = d_samount + d_tagetbalance;
                        Double d_deduct = d_bala - d_samount;
                        target_name.setText(u_name);
                        amount.setText(str_amount);
                        //update sender data
                        mDatabaseUsers.child(userID).child("balance").setValue(d_deduct);
                        mDatabaseUsers.child(userID).child("transactions").push().child("trans").setValue(str_amount + " - " + str_posttime + " - " + "C2C" + " - " + "Sent");

                        //post data transfer
                        mDatabaseUsers.child(str_c2c).child("balance").setValue(send_amount);
                        //for user transactions list
                        mDatabaseUsers.child(str_c2c).child("transactions").push().child("trans").setValue(str_amount + " - " + str_posttime + " - " + "C2C"  + " - " + "Received");
                        //confirm success
                        Toast.makeText(Transfer.this, "Sent successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent sbs = new Intent(Transfer.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(sbs);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        target_name.setText("Your target user was not found!");
                        target_name.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    }
                });

            }

        }else {
            c2c.setError("C2C cant be empty!");
            samount.setError("Enter amount!");
        }
    }
```

When I send data by clicking the submit button I want to create one unique id for each and every data that I post. and inside that id there is child called trans,

Ok the data is actually posting to firebase, but my problem is this: When I push data, inteady of create on field of data (id), it is creating multiple data fields each with its unique id. What I mean is: my app freezes and the data keeps on posting up until i turn off mobile data. I want only one data to be posted, but it is posting unlimited data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're listening to realtime updates to `mDatabaseUsers.child(str_c2c)`. So each time data is written under that location, your `onDataChange` gets called.

Then in this `onDataChange` you write a new child node under `mDatabaseUsers.child(str_c2c)`, so that once again triggers the listener. And then in the `onDataChange` you add another child node, so that once again triggers the listener. This is an infinite loop, which indeed won't stop until you close the app.

The quick fix for this, is to read the value only once, by using:

```
mDatabaseUsers.child(str_c2c).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(....
```